# Calling a method of sub-sub-class

Tags: java, inheritance

I am having issue with calling a method of a class at the 2nd level of inheritance from the super class.
The scenario is this,

```
abstract class SuperClass
{
    public void MethodOne()
    {
        MethodTwo();
    }

    public abstract void MethodTwo();
}

class Sub1 extends SuperClass
{
    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        //code in sub1
    }
}


class Sub2 extends SuperClass
{
    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        //code in sub2
    }
}
```

With the below code I expect the ***MethodTwo()*** from the ***Sub2*** to be called. But the method from ***Sub1*** is getting called. Am I missing something?

```
SuperClass anObj = new Sub2();
anObj.MethodOne();
```

Comment: If by `init()` you mean `MethodOne()`, the `Sub2#MethodTwo()` must have been called. How did you (wrongly) observed that the method from `Sub1` was called?

Comment: that should be MethodOne(). Thank you...

Comment: @sp00m: with the O/P i got...

Comment: @Kannan Then your O/P must be confusing, making you believe the Sub1's method has been called.

Comment: Abstract method cannot have body in Java.

Comment: Given the title of your question "Calling a method of sub-sub-class", shouldn't Sub2 be declared "class Sub2 extends Sub1" ? Otherwise, I don't see any sub-sub-class in your code.

Comment: Kannan, you sure this code compiles? perhaps you are trying to present a simple analogy to some different code that you have. but you are doing it wrong. post a code that complies, but works wrong. as it stands, your code has different problems and hence other users are busy pointing out those rather than hitting the actual question that you have. post actual code.

Comment: An abstract method is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon)

Comment: `+ Sub1::MethodTwo():void`cannot be marked `abstract` as it has a body...

Answer (score 2):

I have combined all of your classes as inner-classes to help me test them. You can remove the "static" keyword from the classes if you put them in different files:

```
public class Example {
    abstract static class SuperClass
    {
        public void MethodOne()
        {
            MethodTwo();
        }

        public abstract void MethodTwo();
    }

    static class Sub1 extends SuperClass
    {
        @Override
        public void MethodTwo()
        {
           System.out.println("Sub1.MethodTwo()");
        }
    }


    static class Sub2 extends SuperClass
    {
        @Override
        public void MethodTwo()
        {
               System.out.println("Sub2.MethodTwo()");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass anObj = new Sub2();
        anObj.MethodOne();
    }
}
```

When I run this class it outputs `Sub2.MethodTwo()`, proving that it does actually work as you expect.

I notice the code you provided is not proper java code, and does not compile. That's because you've marked methods both as `abstract` and then provided an implementation with curly-braces `{  ...  }`.

I assume this is an example of a setup that isn't working for you? If so, I think it doesn't represent your case properly - as it's working as one would expect!

Answer (score 1):

First, you lack the actual implementation of method2.
You should not be able to call an abstract method.

You need to override the abstract in the subclass.

```
class Sub1 extends SuperClass
{
    @override
    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        //code in sub1
    }
}


class Sub2 extends SuperClass
{
    @override
    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        //code in sub2
    }
}
```

This might fix your problem.

Comment: Good point, but this should be a comment rather than an answer ;)

Comment: What does matter is that his methods are not declared `abstract`.

Comment: @Kannan I think @blackbit means the OP forgot to remove the `abstract` modifier of the subclasses' methods.

Comment: That's what I meant. I added the annotations for completeness. :)